# How to use Elasticsearch 6 with Apache, Redis and Varnish on Magento 2.3 Open Source?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, apache2, linux, proxy

**I'm just learning Magento. I have Magento 2.3.3 open source set up on a Linux server with Apache, Redis & Varnish. Next I want to install Elasticsearch 6 ("ES") and I have confusion about some basic concepts.**

> Server info:
>
> - Apache version: 2.4.41 (Unix)
> - Redis version: 5.0.7-1
> - Varnish version: 6.3.1-1 Linux lts 4.19.86-1
> - Elastic search version: 7.4.2-1
> - Elastic search port: 9200

**ES is running and I get the proper response from:**

*- curl localhost:9200
 - curl http://127.0.0.1:9200*

> But I get this error from `curl https://127.0.0.1:9200`

```
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Maybe that is not relevant because none of the articles I have seen on ES mention testing with curl and https.

I'm following this [Magento DevDocs article](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-apache.html).

First, I'm not sure which ports to configure for the http proxy (or, upon further reading, if the http proxy is even needed).

With Varnish, I have Apache listening on port 8080. The [Magento Elasticsearch doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-apache.html) gives an example with Apache listening on the same port. Will that conflict? I'm confused about the http proxy setup.

**I have two modules available:**

```
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_http2_module modules/mod_proxy_http2.so
```

Which is the correct proxy module to enable? With the little I know about http2, it sounds more performant. Will it work with ES?

**Which apache config file should contain these lines?**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have several vhosts defined in `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. Does the ES http proxy affect any of those existing vhosts? Can I just add the above to that same vhosts file?

I also have a `httpd-vhosts-le-ssl.conf` (I'm using Let's Encrypt). Is that config file affected by adding ES?

For Magento 2.3.3 Open Source, I believe I need a marketplace extension for Magento to use ES. I just found [Smile-SA/elasticsuite](https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki/ServerConfig-6.x). That install guide doesn't even mention needing to set up an http proxy with Apache.

For reference, the ES plugins I found are:

- Smile https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite
- Mirasvit https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/elastic-search-ultimate.html
- Webkul https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-Elasticsearch.html
- wyomind https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/elastic-search-magento.html
- Amasty https://marketplace.magento.com/amasty-module-elastic-search.html
- Bingo https://marketplace.magento.com/folio3ecommerce-magento2-module-bingo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to configure proxy. 
your elasticsearch must be running on local or private ip. and magento connects to `9200` port.

but

the only proxy you need is to `kibana` service, configuring that you can set SSL termination and HTTP auth (or use firewall) to open it in your browser.

as example:

proxy domain `elk.myshop.com` that listens on port `9537` to internal kibana port `127.0.0.1:5601`

and access it like: https://elk.myshop.com:9537/

in kibana you can see and manage all indexes and settings for ELK.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering the same and your answer is what I was thinking made sense. Would you (by any chance) know why magento recommends the proxy configuration in the install guide? I mean, the guide doesn't even mention kibana.

Answer (score 0):

Although elastic search module is their in magento2.3 you need to enable elastic search service if elastic search is not installed kindly follow the link https://tigren.com/magento-2-elasticsearch/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand it at all. I am aware of Smile-SA/elasticsuite, but that is only one option of several. I hope maybe you can answer my questions about the http proxy, the port config, etc.